# Decoding dictionary as array in Swift 4

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, codable

My data structure looks like this. "humans" is a dictionary of keys whose values are the dictionary of a human:

```
  "humans" : {
    "abc123" : {
      "name" : "Vince",
      "pets" : [ {
        "animal" : "dog",
        "name" : "Clifford"
      }, {
        "animal" : "fish",
        "name" : "Nemo"
      } ]
    },
    "xyz789" : {
      "name" : "Jack"
    }
  }
```

And so my Swift structs looks like this to match it:

```
struct Human: Codable {
    var name: String!
    var pets: [Pet]?
}

struct Pet: Codable {
    var name: String!
    var animal: Animal!
}

enum Animal: String, Codable {
    case cat
    case dog
    case fish
}
```

I try to decode like this (Using [CodableFirebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase) library):

```
let human = try FirebaseDecoder().decode([Human].self, from: value)
```

But I am getting the following error when trying to encode objects that have arrays of some object:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [], debugDescription: "Not an array", underlyingError: nil))

How can I properly encode a dictionary's values as an array of my custom Swift objects?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few issues:

First of all you are making a common mistake: You are ignoring the root object of the JSON which is a dictionary with one key `humans`. That's the error trying to tell you.

```
struct Root : Codable {
    let humans : [Human]
}

let human = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: value)
```

But even adding the root struct does not work because the value for key `humans` is a dictionary, please note the `{}`

```
struct Root : Codable {
    let humans : [String:Human]
}
```

Finally **never, never, never** declare decodable struct members as implicit unwrapped optionals, either they are non-optional (yes, the code compiles without exclamation marks) or regular optional (`?`)

```
struct Human: Codable {
    var name: String
    var pets: [Pet]?
}

struct Pet: Codable {
    var name: String
    var animal: Animal
}

enum Animal: String, Codable {
    case cat, dog, fish
}
```

---

If you want an `Human` array in the `Root` struct rather than a dictionary you have to write a custom initializer

```
struct Root : Codable{
    let humans : [Human]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let humanData = try container.decode([String:Human].self, forKey: .humans)
        humans = Array(humanData.values)
    }
}
```